# Baking Problem in 3ds max

Tags: 3d, texture, 3ds-max

First of all: I actually checked if 3d software is in this site's scope. Apparently it's kind of grey area but it is [allowed (especially when it comes to texture)](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/554/do-we-still-feel-like-3d-questions-are-out-of-scope-here).

So, I made a low poly model in Autodesk 3ds Max 2014, unwrapped it and baked it (via render to texture, ambient occlusion as diffuse).

I immediately noticed that there's a problem alongside the seams: there were gaps there (see image below), and I couldn't find a way to fix them.

Here's a image showing the difference between the model with no material (and hence the solid white), and a copy of the model with the diffuse map.
[image: Difference]

Seams are in green here:
[image: Seams in green]

The UV template:
[image: UV template]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's downsampling. Read about [EdgePadding](http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Edge_padding). Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please summarise the contents of the linked site? Or add some key points, as otherwise your answer becomes unusable when the posted link rots.